# How to find weak link in internet setup?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

It seems quite a few packets get lost on their way through my wireless setup, but I can't figure out what's the problem. I suspect the packets either get lost between my two wireless routers (one is a repeater) or on the very old and desolate phone line in my house. But it could also be between the other router and my modem, I'm really not sure.

Is there something like traceroute that I can keep running for some time and figure out where the packets get dropped?

Comment: How exactly did you determine you have packets being dropped

Comment: By displaying the lagometer in Quake 3 engine games as well as source engine the packet drop was noticable (besides feeling it).

Comment: percise numbers please.  You verify your latency to the server wasn't the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be difficult to fully track down where the problem lays with this kind of network due to 'hops' being invisible. You can use more advanced tools such as WireShark but it might take you a while to figure it out if you're new to it.

My advice is to use `pathping` from the command line.

I would use it by typing `pathping -4 www.google.co.uk`. This should return with a list of each hop and the results from that section. The weakest gap in the hops would normally be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can [ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) the various equipments that compose your network (the first access point, the repeater, the modem and finally an external host like `8.8.8.8` which is Google's public DNS server) to pinpoint the location of the problem.

```
ping -t <IP address or hostname>
```

(the `-t` option makes it run continuously on Windows, on Linux/UNIX this is not needed as ping runs continuously by default and stop only when you press `Ctrl+C`)

Start with the closest device : the repeater. If there's no packet loss there (let the ping run for a minute or two), then go beyond the repeater : the access point, if no loss there either, then go even farther, etc...